# How to implement a list of multiple elements, where an element can be expanded by click? (Dynamic Outlet Names?)

Tags: ember.js

I want to realize the following concept. Can you give me some hints or keywords at which i should have a look at?

These are my requirements:

- I want to render a list of elements.
- Each element should contain a button. A click on the button should show additional details relating to the clicked element (I do not want to use jquery for a simple hide and show, since this click triggers an additional call to my backend server).

My guess is that it could work like this:

- Implement an ArrayController to control the list of elements.
- The ArrayController should again contain one controller for each of the elements.
- When an element is clicked, the outlet of the elements view should be connected to Controller for the additional details.

These are my problems with that approach:

1. Is this a feasible approach at all?
2. How can i instantiate multiple controllers and pass my elements to it in my template?
3. How can i access the controller for an element, so that i can connect the appropriate controller for the detail view?

Sorry i could no include more Ember Terms in my description. I have just finished the first tutorial and now i need someone to give me the right direction. Thank you! :-)

**-----UPDATE------**

I worked on this problem myself during the weekend and came up with the following solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/SNte7/4/

I think the proposed solution by pangratz (first answer) is good, if one has a simple model like the one he has used. When i saw his answer, i realized that i did not describe my requirements detailed enough. Actually my requirements looks like this:

Initial state of the list

1. First Element
2. Second Element
3. Third Element

After clicking e.g. Item 3, it should show the associated Items of it:

1. First Element
2. Second Element
3. Third Element

   - Associated Item 1 for third Element
   - Associated Item 2 for third Element

Therefore i wanted to have a separate Controller to control the associated Items of my elements in the list. It seemed to me that outlets were the right way to go.

Actually i **had to patch the ember framework** to implement the desired behaviour. Currently i call this feature 'Dynamic Outlet Names'. Currently one can specify outlet names in a HandleBars template, but one cannot use properties of an object to generate those names dynamically. I patched the outlet helper to evaluate wether the String parameter represents a property of an object:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('outlet', function(property, options) {

  if(arguments.length === 3){      
      var optionsTemp = arguments[arguments.length - 1],
      context = arguments[0];
      var temp = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, context, optionsTemp);
      if(temp)
          property = temp;
      options = optionsTemp;
  }else if (property && property.data && property.data.isRenderData) {
     options = property;
     property = 'view';
  } 

  options.hash.currentViewBinding = "controller." + property;

  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.ContainerView, options);
});
```

That way i am able to use an objects property as a value for an outlet name.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items" >
    {{#each item in controller}}
        {{item.description}}
        <button {{action showAssociatedItems item}}>Show Associated Items</button>
        {{outlet item.id asd}}            
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

See my full working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/SNte7/4/

**My Question: What do you think of this solution? Could i have implemented it without patching the framework? As i said, the first proposed solution is good for a simple model. But my feeling is that the associated items should be realised as models and should therefore be controlled by an Ember Controller.**

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `ArrayController` which holds all elements which shall be shown. The setting - wether the details of an object shall be shown or not - should in my opinion be handled by the view, so I wouldn't create a controller instance for each item. The view which shows a single item shall keep the bookmarking wether the details are shown or not. So you could do something along the following lines, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/ASHFa/:

**Handlebars**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items" >
    {{#each item in controller itemViewClass="App.ItemView"}}
        {{item.description}} <button {{action toggleDetail}}>{{view.toggleDetailText}}</button>
        {{#if view.showDetail}}
            <img {{bindAttr src="item.img"}}>
        {{/if}}        
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ItemsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'items'
});

App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    toggleDetailText: function() {
        return this.get('showDetail') ? 'hide' : 'show';
    }.property('showDetail'),

    toggleDetail: function() {
        this.toggleProperty('showDetail');
    }
});

App.itemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [{
        description: 'first item',
        img: 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ll3y1pZDVJ1qb08qmo1_250.jpg'
    }, {
        description: 'second item',
        img: 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lk7u170Ztt1qb33vho1_250.jpg'
    }, {
        description: 'third item',
        img: 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lj5367UKg11qzgqodo1_250.jpg'
    }]
});

App.ItemsView.create({
    controllerBinding: 'App.itemsController'
}).append();
```

​

Comment: Hey pangratz,
thanks for your feedback. When reading your answer, i realized that i did not describe my requirements good enough. Could you have a look at the update of my question? Tell me what you think about it!