# How can we load multiple instances into a template?

Tags: ember.js

We're trying to put together a portal, where a layout can have any number of core widgets in any sequence in the main layout.

To simulate this, we've got a number of outlets:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

{{outlet pos1}}
{{outlet pos2}}
{{outlet pos3}}
{{outlet pos4}}
{{outlet pos5}}
{{outlet pos6}}
{{outlet pos7}}
{{outlet pos8}}
{{outlet pos9}}
{{outlet pos10}}
```

And in the router, we're attempting to load them in one by one:

```
  connectOutlets: function(router, group) {
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('group', group);
    router.get('groupController').connectOutlet('pos9', 'toDo', App.ToDo.find(41));
    router.get('groupController').connectOutlet('pos3', 'toDo', App.ToDo.find(15));
```

However, when there are more than one, the final context is used. So in this example, we get two instances of the toDo object, both of which are for id #15.

Am I approaching this in the right way and is it possible to do this programatically, rather than having a fixed layout of outlets?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: My answer is based on the assumption that this complex solution is really needed in your case. Based on your simple example one could also say, that you could use an ArrayController for all your ToDo items. But here is my try on the answer to the complex problem:**

the problem are the following 2 lines:

```js
router.get('groupController').connectOutlet('pos9', 'toDo', App.ToDo.find(41));
router.get('groupController').connectOutlet('pos3', 'toDo', App.ToDo.find(15));
```

What you basically do there is:

1. Connect the outlet with name pos9 with the Controller named 'todo'. Set the content of this controller to ToDo with Id 41.
2. Connect the outlet with name pos3 with the Controller named 'todo'. Set the content of this controller to ToDo with Id 15 (so you are overriding the content of the same controller).
3. The result is that you end up with both outlets connected to the same instance of a controller. And you the same ToDos since you have set the content property of this single instance twice. **The core problem is from my point of view: EmberJS uses single instances of controllers by default.**

So my solution approach would be to instantiate a new Controller for each outlet you have. Unfortunately this also requires modification to the lookup of the View. As you likely know, Controller and View are matched by name. So roughly the algorithm would be in pseudocode:

1. Create new instance of Controller, e.g.: var newController = App.ToDoController.create();
2. Inject this controller into the router with the appropriate name, e.g. router.set('todoControllerForPos9', newController);
3. Based on this name, you must enable Ember to find the matching view, e.g. App.set('TodoControllerForPos9View', App.ToDoView);
4. Finally call connectOutlet on the router, e.g.: router.get('groupController').connectOutlet('pos9', 'todoControllerForPos9', App.ToDo.find(41));

As you might guess, i ran into this problem myself. I did ask this question before and this is the solution, i came up with. I think, this is a missing feature i ember. I call it dynamic outlet names. See my original question here: [How to implement a list of multiple elements, where an element can be expanded by click? (Dynamic Outlet Names?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056851/how-to-implement-a-list-of-multiple-elements-where-an-element-can-be-expanded-b)

Have a look at the Update section and the fiddle provided there and you will recognize my pseudo code provided here.

**It would be still great, if someone could have a look at my solution, because it is still hacky at the moment, but seems valueable to me. Hope this will gain some attention now with this big answer :-)**